# Change member name on serializer of Django REST framework

Tags: python, django

I am using serializer of `Django REST framework`

```
class SpotSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    key = serializers.IntegerField()
```

which has field `key`

and serialized class has `key`

```
class Spot: 
    def __init__(self, key)
        self.key = key
```

output of SpotSerializer will be json and pass to as API response.

```
{
    "key": 2,
}
```

However I would like to change the name. `key` -> `spot_id`

like this below, just change the label name

```
{
    "spot_id": 2,
}
```

Is it possible ?

```
 serializers.IntegerField(label="spot_id")
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `spot_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='key')`? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source

Comment: Thank you it works. maybe I understood vice versa/